# How to convert [u64;N] to [u8;8*N]?

Tags: rust

I am writing a compression algorithm in Rust.

I have a "conversion table" which maps input bytes to outputs (each output is a `u64` which is the code, and a `u8` which is the length of the code, which need not be a multiple of 8). For each input byte, I find the corresponding output and bit-shift the code into a large contiguous array of `u64`s. I then want to write this array of `u64`s to a file.

What would be the best way to convert the `[u64; WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE]` to a `[u8; 8 * WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE]`?

Is looping through `[u64; WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE]`, calling `to_be_bytes()` on each `u64`, writing each byte of this to the `[u8; 8*WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE]` the best I can do?

I saw examples of `align_to` which required unsafe, which seems excessive just to convert data types. I also saw [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250300/convert-array-of-u32-to-vecu8-in-rust) which outputs a `Vec`. I think this just pushes the problem down the road, though, because I still have to convert that `Vec<u8>` into an `[u8]` to write to the file. Am I wrong?

Comment: I suspect calling `to_be_bytes` in a loop is the best you can do, that's also what your linked answer does. Also note, `Vec<T>` [dereferences](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.deref) into `[T]`, so you don't have to worry about converting. (Though for performance, note that `Vec` allocates.) Lastly, I'd like to leave [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/intrinsics/fn.transmute.html) here, which is likely not what you want, because it doesn't take care of endianness.

Comment: Is big-endian necessary? Little-endian is the one with the potential of being free of cost on most platforms.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Project Safe Transmute](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-safe-transmute). Note however it is not implemented yet, not even proposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`bytemuck`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/) crate provides functions for reinterpreting one type as another without use of `unsafe`, whenever this is safe because both types are “just bytes” (have no invalid values and no padding). Just call `bytemuck::cast` to convert between any integer array type, as long as both types are the same total size. (Or, `bytemuck::cast_slice` if you have a slice of integers or integer arrays.)

Such conversions are purely changing the *type*, and so they have no run-time cost. However, they do not reorder bytes to a specific endianness, so this exposes the native endianness of the machine you're running on. In your case, perhaps you can rearrange your table to solve this more efficientl than explicitly swapping the bytes. If you can't, then probably `to_be_bytes` in a loop is as good as it gets.

```rust
const WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE: usize = 4;

fn main() {
    let sixtyfours: [u64; WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE] = [1, 2, 3, 0x0102030405060708];
    let eights: [u8; 8 * WRITE_CHUNK_SIZE] = bytemuck::cast(sixtyfours);
    println!("{:?}", eights);
}
```

This prints (on a little-endian machine):

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```